# How can i get those id which has all status?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database table with two columns: `id` and `status`.

`status` can have three different values, `A`, `B` and `C`.

I now want to get those `id`s which have all three different statuses (`A`, `B` and `C`).

```
id status
 1 A
 2 A
 1 B
 3 A
 3 B
 3 C
```

Comment: What do you mean by all status ? please add proper description in your question

Comment: It's disappointing that no one suggested an exclusion join

Comment: @Strawberry looks interesting, wouldn't like to write one about this yourself ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `HAVING`:

```
SELECT id
FROM tab
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT status) = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT STATUS) FROM tab);
```

And to get full rows:

```
SELECT *
FROM tab
WHERE id IN ( SELECT id
              FROM tab
              GROUP BY id
              HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT status) = 
                   (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT STATUS)  FROM tab) 
            );
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=5093da3ab363e256642ac8cbe0a7f480)**

Answer (score 1):

I'm making 2 assumptions in my answer. You know it's 'A', 'B' and 'C' and these statuses will only appear once. Perhaps there's a UNIQUE constraint on (id,status).

```
SELECT id FROM tab GROUP BY id HAVING (COUNT(1) == 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you status columns are fix,

Then you can try something like below

```
select id, count(distinct `status`) as ct from tab group by id having ct=3
```

Check [Here](http://rextester.com/JFVX39394)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is helpful:

```
SELECT
  id,
  `status`,
  COUNT(tab.status) AS s
FROM
  tab
GROUP BY id
HAVING s = 3
```